# IntelliJ IDEA 'wrong attribute value' warning in translate attr

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a next line:

```
<p translate="key"></p>
```

IntelliJ warns me: *'wrong attribute value'*. I have `<!doctype html>` in my .html file. How to disable this inspection or make it not warn me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, translate attribute must contains boolean value. For translations, use data-translate or x-translate.

Answer (score 2):

I just recently figure it out with my co-worker, so you can disable notification and code analysis for any attribute in this case "translate"

In webstorm it is Settings -> Language Injection Settings -> add 
Local Name is regex so '.*' is for all tags but you can set multiple tags like 'div|span'

Hope it helps

[image: Language injection settings]